# Parse Xml In C# (WebTut)

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

Got a problem here with parsing Xml in C#. I am trying to run some code i found from this site:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24049/Easy-XML-Parsing-in-C

The code is:

```
namespace ParseXML
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                TextReader reader = new StreamReader("notes.xml");
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(note));
                note n = (note)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

                System.Console.WriteLine(n.to);
                System.Console.WriteLine(n.from);
                System.Console.WriteLine(n.heading);
                System.Console.WriteLine(n.body);
                reader.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

        }        
    }
}
```

You will see 'note' being passing into Xmlserializer (XmlSerializer(typeof(note))) - what does this note mean there is no type for note. The line underneath contains a further two instances of note and ALL have the red underline saying i have missed an assembly reference. There are no namespaces for note. This guy seems to have just added this to screw with people. Its absolutely maddening

Comment: Oh no please! You should start by reading a tutorial, specially a C# tutorial. There's no way you will understand any answer here if you don't know concepts such as an object in OOP and explicit casting

Comment: Your code isn't even _parsing_ XML. Please start by getting some clue about what you're doing, and don't just do copy/paste/ask.

Comment: @John Saunders - That code is so parsing XML. It is using an XmlSerializer to parse it. Its a very common technique.

Comment: Its absolutely maddening to see people asking such questions.

Comment: @Ahsan - agreed. But its more maddening to see people with huge reputation on SO making accusations without knowing what they are talking about. "Your code isn't even parsing XML" - pfft. Pick up a C# textbook.

Comment: The `XmlReader` is doing the parsing. This code is _deserializing_ XML, which is not generally considered as "parsing".

Comment: @John Saunders - I disagree. The XmlSerializer is "parsing" the XML, in the strict sense that it is extracting semantic meaning from the input text. The distinction that you are trying to form is laughably marginal, and clearly arguing to try be "right". I hope you can "parse" this comment, though I doubt it.

Answer (score 3):

No, the guy is not messing with you. Note is an automatically generated class from the file notes.xsd.

The process is:

1. define your data structure in the XSD
2. use Microsoft' XSD.EXE to generate a .CS file from the XSD
3. Include the generated CS file into your solution

then the type will become available.

To the people who suggested that he isn't parsing XML, what do you think this line is doing:

```
note n = (note)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

Frying some bacon and eggs?

Comment: That line is _deserializing_ XML, by calling the `XmlReader` instance to parse it.

Comment: So, it _is_ parsing it, just indirectly, correct? Otherwise I could argue that XmlReader doesn't _parse_ XML, because its the IL inside XmlReader doing the parsing. Maybe stop trying to one-up people and try be helpful?